# The functions system or shell in R Studio do not work on my string on Windows 10. Running command had status 1

Tags: r, shell, cmd, system

When I run the string below in my command line, it works fine. But when I run it from R, it does not.

I run this:

`>cmd <- "python -c 'import sys; import pandas; import scrublet; df = pandas.read_csv(\"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpOmMtOp\\file383068ca4fa\"); scrub = scrublet.Scrublet(df); doublet_scores, predicted_doublets = scrub.scrub_doublets(); pandas.DataFrame(doublet_scores).to_csv(\"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpOmMtOp\\file383068ca4fa.doubletScores\");'"`

`tmp <- system(cmd, intern=T)`

> Warning message:
> In system(cmd, intern = T) :
> running command 'python -c 'import sys; import pandas; import scrublet; df = pandas.read_csv("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOmMtOp\file383068ca4fa"); scrub = scrublet.Scrublet(df); doublet_scores, predicted_doublets = scrub.scrub_doublets(); pandas.DataFrame(doublet_scores).to_csv("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOmMtOp\file383068ca4fa.doubletScores");'' had status 1

Comment: It seems suspicious you are trying to read private application temp files. Are you sure those files exist when you run the R code?

Comment: I created it using tf <- tempfile()
[some code] 
  data.table::fwrite(dt,file=tf). It really exists, I checked manually. For the sake of simplicity I've put here an example. Moreover, when I run it from CMD, I get the results

Comment: Does `Sys.which("python")` return a path to python? Can you run any other python commands or is it just the one that gives the error?

Comment: If it runs in the command line, maybe you should be using `shell(cmd,...)` instead of `system(cmd, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks everybody, problem solved. I just changed all the "\" with "/"